# Is screen mirroring/remote control faster via USB or Wifi

Tags: screen-mirroring, airdroid

I use Airdroid via wifi to remotely control the device from PC, but I also want a high definition mirroring. Is mirroring/remote control faster via wifi or usb? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't answer this question in general as there are phones with USB 2.0 and other with USB 3.0 connection. Note that a phone having an USB-C connection can be USB 2.0 or 3.0, thus the USB-C port doesn't tell you anything on the connection speed. Only if the phone has an Micro-USB connection it is USB 2.0 for sure.

USB in general should have a lower latency and is more reliable as Wifi uses a shared media and thus can be disturbed by other devices using the same frequencies.

If the phone supports USB 3 modes then it should also be faster than WiFi. Most USB 2.0 devices usually get around 30MB/sec (240MBit), so some Wifi set-ups may be faster but that depends on the Wifi modes supported by the phone, the used Wifi router and the Ethernet connection between PC and router (a connection WiFi-to-Wifi is almost never faster than USB 2.0).

But even if it only supports USB 2.0 then it may be the preferred connection, unless you try to use the phone for remotely viewing videos or other situations where the display is constantly changing.